# dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib and @rpath/libintl.8.dylib

Tags: r, xcode, macos, conda, dylib

I just installed the new update on OSX because it kept popping up.  Of course, it broke something.  I can't access my R anymore.

Took me forever to get my environment set up.  I have all of my R packages installed with the R I'm using in conda.

**How can I fix this?** Why do dyld libraries always break when I do any updates or slight tweaks? It really messes up the workflow...

````
Joshs-MBP:~ mu$ which R
/Users/mu/anaconda/bin/R
Joshs-MBP:~ mu$ R
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mu/anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```
````

I'm running OSX Sierra 10.12.6 it literally broke immediately when it started updating Xcode (I thought it was just updating my iTunes).

```
Joshs-MBP:~ mu$ conda info
Current conda install:

               platform : osx-64
          conda version : 4.3.29
       conda is private : False
      conda-env version : 4.3.29
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.6.3.final.0
       requests version : 2.18.4
       root environment : /Users/mu/anaconda  (writable)
    default environment : /Users/mu/anaconda
       envs directories : /Users/mu/anaconda/envs
                          /Users/mu/.conda/envs
          package cache : /Users/mu/anaconda/pkgs
                          /Users/mu/.conda/pkgs
           channel URLs : https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/osx-64
                          https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/pro/noarch
            config file : None
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
             user-agent : conda/4.3.29 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.3 Darwin/16.7.0 OSX/10.12.6
                UID:GID : 501:20
```

I tried https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/6312 but now there's a different but similar error:

```
Joshs-MBP:~ mu$ R
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/mu/anaconda/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6183

Try : `conda update -c rdonnellyr -c main --all`

[image]

https://github.com/mingwandroid has a great explanation in what's happening with `R`, `dylib`, and `MacOS`

Comment: I´m sorry, I had the same issue and this code suggested by mingwandroid did not work on my computer (macbook pro, macOS High Sierra 10.13.14). Does anyone know what else could I do? My error message is: "dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /anaconda3/lib/R/lib/libR.dylib
  Reason: image not found"

Comment: I ended up creating a series of scripts to get my `R` and `Python` compatible in the same environment which was the source for all of this mess.  https://github.com/jolespin/install_main_environment

Comment: A fresh reinstallation was the only thing that consistently worked. I highly recommend having a script to automate this process. I spent a week of frustration before I figured this out. Also, to test module installations one by one in a cloned environment will save you some trouble.

Comment: Do you have that script, already? Because I checked your github scripts of install_main_environment and I wasn´t sure which one goes in which order, etc. I reinstalled R using conda and homebrew but it didn´t work. Maybe I first have to uninstall R and then install it again?

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't clear.  I would just download the whole repository, individually open the R install and Python install and comment out the ones you dont want.  Run the main install script.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to update r-base

```
$ conda update -n base r-base
```

This worked for me

Comment: In my case R was not able to link the lib in the newly created conda environment and this worked for me on mac (M1 chip)

Answer (score 1):

Had latest working `Anaconda` and `R`.

Tried `conda update -c rdonnellyr -c main --all`, but without luck.

Following https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/6183#issuecomment-830132824, duplicated and renamed `anaconda3/lib/libreadline.8.1.dylib` to `anaconda3/lib/libreadline.6.2.dylib`. The error message changed and started to complain about another lib, in my case, `libicuuc.54.dylib`, and then `libicui18n.54.dylib`. Repeated similar steps for them, and successfully got R to work in jupyter notebook.

However, rpy2 failed to run with the above work-around, because `dlopen` will check version-specific symbols inside the file and cannot be fooled simply by renaming the file.

This is probably a "mixing channel problem". Following https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html, the issue was solved by installing `r-essentials` explicitly from `conda-forge` channel in a clean conda environment:

```
conda create --name r-tutorial pandas
conda activate r-tutorial
conda install -c conda-forge r-essentials
pip install rpy2
```