# OSError: cannot load library rpy2

Tags: python, rpy2

I am running the following code:

```
# This is a setup cell so that Python and R can run in the same Jupyter notebook
# and so that the text of plots is bigger by default.
import altair as alt

# Set a bigger default font size for plots
def bigger_font():
    return {
        'config': {
            'view': {'continuousWidth': 400, 'continuousHeight': 300},
            'legend': {'symbolSize': 14, 'titleFontSize': 14, 'labelFontSize': 14}, 
            'axis': {'titleFontSize': 15, 'labelFontSize': 12},
            'encoding': {'x': {'scale': {'zero': False}}}}}
alt.themes.register('bigger_font', bigger_font)
alt.themes.enable('bigger_font')

# Ensure that altair plots show up in the exported HTML
# Save a vega-lite spec and a PNG blob for each plot in the notebook
alt.renderers.enable('mimetype')
# Handle large data sets without embedding them in the notebook
alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')

# Load the extension so that we can use the %%R cell magic
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
```

and I'm getting the following error for the rpy2 extension part of the code above:

[image]

Why am I getting this and how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Is this in Jupyter?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libreadline.6.2.dylib and @rpath/libintl.8.dylib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46800784/dyld-library-not-loaded-rpath-libreadline-6-2-dylib-and-rpath-libintl-8-dyli)

Comment: @SuperStormer yes jupyterlab

Comment: @SuperStormer thankfully when i created a new environment and downloaded r-essentials and rpy2 on there, it worked, one of the solutions in the above link worked